# Kotlin coroutines for muliplte database calls

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am pretty new to Kotlin coroutines and want to introduce them in our application for a requirement where I have to make three read calls to the database, basically fetching data from different tables and returning an entity combining the data from the three calls.

Here is the code snippet that I prepared, which seems to be working fine.

```
return runBlocking {
      val firstResult = async { dbReadOne(param1, param2).verySmallProcessing() }
      val secondResult = async {
        repo.dbReadTwo(
          param1,
          param2
        )
      }
      val thirdResult = async {
        repo.dbReadThree(
          param1,
          param2
        )
      }

    X(firstResult.await(),
        secondResult.await().takeIf { it.isPresent }
          ?.let {//some processing here}, 
       thirdResult.await().takeIf { it.isPresent }
          ?.let {//some processing here})
    }
```

I have a couple of queries here, and I want to know about improvements to the code.

a) Am I using runBlocking correctly here, or should I wrap my three calls in a different construct like coroutineScope?

b) Is it OK to return from runBlocking? Or shall I make the scope of runBlocking() smaller, but in that case, how will I get the values back from the async calls?

Comment: Guess that the 3 read db operation do not have order or dependency, correct?

Comment: Yes, they are not dependent on each other.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can improve your code by wrapping it in

```kotlin
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
  // your code here
}
```

2. Use coroutineScope which is non blocking, meaning it does not block main thread
3. You can return normally when using coroutine